# visual studio и перегрузка операторов

Tags: c++, visual-c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class pop {
    int x;

 public:
    int getX() {
        return x;
    }
    pop() : x{ 0 } {}

    pop operator + (pop& p) {
        return pop(this->x + p.x);
        // здесь ошибка E0289: отсутствуют экземпляры конструктора pop::pop,
        // соответствуюшие списку аргументов; и всегда у меня ошибки с
        // перегрузкой в vs
    }
};
```

Comment: Вызываете конструктор `pop(int)`, которого нет..

Answer (score 5):

- Вам нужен конструктор для класса `pop`, который принимает один параметр типа `int`. Вы в вашем `return` пытаетесь использовать именно его, но создать его вы забыли.

  Этот конструктор может быть отдельным конструктором, но можно, если вам понравится, воспользовавшись аргументами по умолчанию, написать один общий конструктор: и для конструкции из `int`, и для конструкции по умолчанию

  ```
  pop(int x = 0) : x{ x } {}
  ```

  Также, если вы не объявите такой конструктор `explicit`, то он будет *конструктором преобразования* и в реализации вашего оператора вы сможете, при желании, просто написать

  ```
  return x + p.x;
  ```

  Но это дело вкуса.
- Бинарный оператор сложения лучше реализовывать самостоятельной (возможно дружественной) функцией, а не методом класса, как у вас. Однако даже при реализации методом класса не стоит забывать о константной корректности

  ```
  pop operator + (const pop& p) const
  ```

  и, конечно

  ```
  int getX() const
  ```
- Если вы предоставите конструктор конверсии из типа `int`, вы сразу же сможете также выполнять сложения вида

  ```
  pop a, b;
  a = b + 5; 
  // Автоматически рассматривается компилятором как `b + pop(5)`
  ```

  Однако из-за того, что оператор сложения у вас реализован методом класса, вы не сможете выполнять сложения вида

  ```
  a = 5 + b;
  ```

  Реализация оператора сложения самостоятельной функцией была бы свободна от этого недостатка.